# Estimation methods for panel vector error correction model (VECM)

Tags: statistics, time-series, panel-data

I have three variables for T= 40 and N= 4, I want to apply the panel VECM model. There are softwares where I can rum this model such as EViews. But I need estimation methods that can be used to estimate the model parameters. Can you help in sharing the name of those methods and articles (if you know)?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating a VECM model where all cross-sectional units enter the equations of each other will be risky, since your time series is rather short.

A way to estimate a VECM can be found in [Johansen (1995)](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=BH7nCwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=johansen%201995%20likelihood-based%20inference&ots=Zit4ZgoqSI&sig=To9TCWdL2e0kLJhMOkT4nZq1qdA#v=onepage&q=johansen%201995%20likelihood-based%20inference&f=false). Using his method you can enter cross sections as exogenous.
Further, [this thread](http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?t=18039) in the EViews forum might help you.

You could also try different approaches such as methods introduced in [Canova and Ciccarelli (2013)](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/153940/1/ecbwp1507.pdf) or a [global VECM](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/joes.12095).